# Receiving error "Cannot listen to an undefined element" when inserting code for a Facebook page plugin

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to insert a Facebook page plugin on my Wordpress site. When I insert the iframe of the Facebook page plugin, the plugin shows correctly on my site but on the developer tools console I'm seeing the following error:

> ErrorUtils caught an error: "Cannot listen to an undefined element. TAAL[2]". VM443242 Nj_EK_LUrYY.js:57 ErrorUtils caught an error: "Cannot listen to an undefined element. TAAL[2]". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.

What could be causing this, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: have you found the solution for this ?

Comment: Looks like fb has a problem in their likebox plugin. At some point the script tries to listen to an element which is not present inside likebox iframe. The problem starts with `require("InitialJSLoader").handleServerJS` which passes, a list of class selectors which will be listened to later. The problem class seems to be (for the plugin version which I checked) **"._ew1"** which should map to `PAGE_SHARE` action. But Share button is not present in the box. Nevertheless, likebox plugin is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/) in favor of Page Plugin

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I´m also having this problem, and my websites are not under Wordpress. They are pure HTML with PHP, using the likebox plugin. I´m almost sure @cephuo is correct... maybe we´ll need to look for an alternative solution for the FB looklike plugin.

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1337180213092053

Answer (score 0):

As also discussed [*here*](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/taal-and-preload-problems/) this problem happen only with `Facebook.js`. However that error: `Cannot listen to an undefined element. TAAL[2]` is dissapear when I upgraded jQuery.

This error might be caused by jquery event aliases like .load, .unload or .error deprecated since jQuery 1.8. Look for these aliases in your code and replace them with .on() to register listeners instead. Example:

```
$(window).load(function(){...});
```

becomes:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});
```